# Compare two NSMutableArray indices in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray, compare

I want to compare two array indices,

```
for (int i=0; i<[CustomeDateArray count]; i++)
  {
      if (([CustomeDateArray objectAtIndex:1] == [newDateArray objectAtIndex:1]) && ([CustomeDateArray objectAtIndex:2] == [newDateArray objectAtIndex:2]))          
                {
                    exists=TRUE;
                    NSLog(@"exists=TRUE");
                }
  }
```

**My Log shows this Results:**

```
 CustomeDateArray at Index1=06
 CustomeDateArray at Index2=2012
        
 newDateArray at Index1=06
 newDateArray at Index2=2012
```

If my `if` condition is true then control should go inside and it should print `exists=TRUE`
but i am unable to see `exists=TRUE` control is not going inside.

What's the problem?

Comment: So, `TRUE` is the same as `YES` in Objective-C, and `FALSE` is the same as `NO`, but you should try getting used to using `YES` and `NO`. All of Apple's sample code uses them and so does most of the code I've ever seen on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<[CustomeDateArray count]; i++)
  {
          if (([[CustomeDateArray objectAtIndex:1] isEqual:[newDateArray objectAtIndex:1]]) && ([[CustomeDateArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqual:[newDateArray objectAtIndex:2]]))        
                {
                    exists=TRUE;
                    NSLog(@"exists=TRUE");
                }
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to use `isEqual:` not `isEqualToString:` but this is totally the right way to compare Objective-C objects.

Comment: +1 But just one observation: If the items in the arrays are not `NSString`s you may need to use `isEqual` instead of `isEqualToString`.

Comment: For a little clarification: Objective-C objects are pointers to memory. In other words, what you're doing there with the `==` operator is asking if they are the **same object**, that is, the same location in memory, not if their *values* are the same. The `isEqual:` method is defined on NSObject, and is used to compare the **values** of two objects. If you know both objects are strings, `isEqualToString:` is faster than `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see to kind of problems in your code:

1. why you are looping inside CustomDateArray (for loop) and you are not using the index "i"?
   (this is not relevant to the specific question, but just check your code for typos!)
2. more specific to your question: NSArray contains objects and objects in Obj-C are pointers, so your "==" just compares pointers. This means that:

```
if([CustomDateArray objectAtIndex:1]==[CustomDateArray objectAtIndex:2]) ...
```

corresponds to:

```
id obj1 = [CustomDateArray objectAtIndex:1];
id obj2 = [CustomDateArray objectAtIndex:2];
if(obj1==obj2) ...
```

The "if" will return true only if obj1 and obj2 point to the same address, so they are exactly the same object. But if the purpose of your check is to know if the two dates are the same date, then you should use the NSDate specific comparison methods:

```
NSDate *d1 = [CustomDateArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSDate *d2 = [CustomDateArray objectAtIndex:2];
if([d1 isEqualToDate:d2]) ...
```

Instead, if the objects are string, you should use the "isEqualToString:" method.